# Civi CRM - Multiple events / memberships within 1 basket?

Tags: wordpress, payment, integration

Does anyone know if it is possible to integrate the CRM so you can add multiple things (memberships / event tickets etc) into a basket, and then pay for all of these at once?

TIA - I cant find any info on this anywhere!

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: Dave do you want to clarify or give some examples of the 'mix'. Eg yes Demerit is right that you can use Price Sets to eg have multiple memberships on a page, but not sure that will work for combining memberships with events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're prepared to install WooCommerce (caveat: it's pretty heavy on a server and some hosts may not support it) then you can achieve what you're after using the [Integrate CiviCRM with WooCommerce](https://github.com/WPCV/wpcv-woo-civi-integration) plugin.

Comment: Thanks! Is this something you have developed for a specific project (I can see your contributions)? Do you have an example of a site where its being used please?

Answer (score 2):

**For adding multiple events into a cart:**
Admin >> CiviEvent >> CiviEvent Component Settings

In there, check off "Use Shopping Cart Style Event Registration" (it says it's in alpha state, and it's been that way ever since we started using CiviCRM, which was in 2014 ... so, there's that. We explored this, and it was completely unusable on a Joomla install; can't comment on other CMS's, but thought I'd mention it in case you were willing to test it on your end)

**For purchasing an event + membership:**
https://aghstrategies.com/event-additional-signup-extension/

(it has some drawbacks, described on the page linked above; we had some other specifics for our use case so ended up not using it)

CiviCRM does need a proper shopping cart that will work hand in hand with CiviDiscount (i.e. if you purchase an event and membership, and the membership should give you a discount on the event, it'll get applied correctly in the cart). Assuming this would require a "make it happen" kind of campaign.

The way we work around it we try to curate the user flows. E.g., we know most folks start with purchasing an event so right on the registration form, we tell them "hey, did you know you can get a discount if you become a member - sign up here (link)". It's not perfect, but it's getting us by.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - appreciate your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like price sets is what you're looking for: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/membership-price-sets/#non-membership-price-fields

Comment: I didn't think it was the case for combining memberships and events, nor multiple events (if that is what the OP is asking).